# Should I create many singletons or singleton context with references to my state and objects?

Tags: java, architecture, singleton, guice

I am using Guice in a project. Since it is the first time, I am wondering about how to keep and pass around state, i.e. objects that contain some user input or long lived objects that are needed elsewhere (not where they were injected the first time).

For instance, my application has a Server which the user can start and stop. Furthermore, the user can enter some data which leads to state that needs to be preserved in memory.

At the moment I see two possibilities:

1. have a `Context` class with scope `@Singleton` and some references to other classes that keep my state and offer me certain functionality.
   The `Context` class would give me access to the `Server` instance, to user data, other services etc.
   The instances of the `Context` may be injected by Guice.
   Thus, if I want to stop my server, I would require the `Context` as a dependency (and not the server).

This goes a bit against the recommendation on the Guice website (inject direct dependencies instead of accessing the "real" dependency with chained getters).

2. annotate all classes with `@Singleton` that should exist only once and are injected in several other classes. As a consequence, I would have only a singleton server, somewhere a class with the user data, etc.

The singleton pattern (GoF) is said to be bad design. Thus, I am wondering whether I should minimize the use of `@Singleton` or whether this is a different story using Guice respectively dependency injection in general.

Are there any other possibilities or a better approach?

Comment: The singleton pattern (GoF) is not the same as the singleton scope.  The arguments against the singleton pattern generally don't apply to the singleton scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of your questions is related to Dependency Injection Paradigm. first of all Using DI doesn't mean every managed bean should be Singleton. The managed beans have their own life cycle. they can be instantiated on every access / request / session or being singleton.

The other thing you should be care about is with DI we usually wire-up our main application design. you should think of your domain objects and their relations instead of DI(Guice/Spring).

for instance in your case if you need a Service Object in a bean so you have the relationship between these two classes and no need to to have a relation to Context!

if data inserted by different users are visible to all users so make the service singleton in your application. if the states of Server bean for each user are different so make the scope of bean Session to allow every user have his own Server bean.